# How can I fix this LINQ so that it treats a pairs of vals as a distinct value?

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, let

The database I'm working with stores a pair of double values in two integer columns.

IOW, Department is a double with values such as 42.12, but is stored in a Dept column (which holds 42 in this case) and a Subdept column (which holds 12 in this case). Don't ask me why (because you'd be disappointed; I can't tell you why, because I don't know).

I need to get a subset of data such as "all the department records between 8.79 and 98.87"

I have this code:

```
public IEnumerable<InventoryItem> GetDepartmentRange(double deptBegin, double deptEnd, string dbContext)
{
    LoadInventoryItems(dbContext);
    // Break the doubles into their component parts:
    var deptStartWhole = (int)Math.Truncate(deptBegin);
    var startFraction = (int)((deptBegin - deptStartWhole) * 100);
    var deptEndWhole = (int)Math.Truncate(deptEnd);
    var endFraction = (int)((deptBegin - deptEndWhole) * 100);

    return inventoryItems
        .Where(d => d.dept >= deptStartWhole)
        .Where(e => e.subdept >= startFraction)
        .Where(f => f.dept <= deptEndWhole)
        .Where(g => g.subdept >= endFraction)
        //.Where(g => g.subdept <= endFraction)
        .OrderBy(o => o.dept)
        .ThenBy(s => s.subdept);
}
```

...but it doesn't quite work - with the above query (Depts between 8.79 and 98.87) it shows depts that are 98.88, which is one beyond what I want.

I tried the commented-out line, but that made it even worse (nothing returned at all).

My intuition tells me I may need a "let" here, but don't know just how to go about it.

### UPDATE

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since in you're example you're multiplying the fraction by 100, i'm assuming the `subdept` value would only have two digits. If it's the case, perhaps you could try the following code:

```
public IEnumerable<InventoryItem> GetDepartmentRange(double deptBegin, double deptEnd, string dbContext)
{           
  LoadInventoryItems(dbContext);

  return inventoryItems
    .Where(d => ((d.dept * 100 + d.subdept) >= deptBegin * 100) &&       
                ((d.dept * 100 + d.subdept) <= deptEnd * 100))
    .OrderBy(o => o.dept)
    .ThenBy(s => s.subdept);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your endFraction calculation is wrong:

```
public IEnumerable<InventoryItem> GetDepartmentRange(double deptBegin, double deptEnd, string dbContext)
{
    LoadInventoryItems(dbContext);
    // Break the doubles into their component parts:
    int deptStartWhole = (int)Math.Truncate(deptBegin);
    int startFraction = (int)((deptBegin - deptStartWhole) * 100);
    int deptEndWhole = (int)Math.Truncate(deptEnd);
    int endFraction = (int)((deptEnd - deptEndWhole) * 100);

    return inventoryItems
        .Where(d => d.dept >= deptStartWhole)
        .Where(e => e.subdept >= startFraction)
        .Where(f => f.dept <= deptEndWhole)
        .Where(g => g.subdept >= endFraction)
        .OrderBy(o => o.dept)
        .ThenBy(s => s.subdept);
}
```

Comment: That helped a little (it gave me two valid records that previously weren't getting returned), but I still have the bogus/unwanted (98.88) record.

Comment: Hmm.  Is it only getting .01 beyond?  there might be other issues

Answer (score 3):

You are using a wrong variable in your calculation here:

```
var endFraction = (int)((deptBegin - deptEndWhole) * 100);
```

Replace `deptBegin` with `deptEnd` to fix this.

Making this change appears to produce the desired values when tested with the following code:

```
public void ShowDeptRange(double deptBegin, double deptEnd)
{
    // Break the doubles into their component parts:
    var deptStartW = (int)Math.Truncate(deptBegin);
    var deptStartF = (int)((deptBegin - deptStartW) * 100);
    var deptEndW = (int)Math.Truncate(deptEnd);
    var deptEndF = (int)((deptEnd - deptEndW) * 100);

    Console.WriteLine("{0}.{1}, {2}.{3}",
        deptStartW, deptStartF, deptEndW, deptEndF);
}

void Main()
{
    ShowDeptRange(8.79, 98.87);
}
```

Also [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21743074/148634), which addresses problems with your query's logic.

Comment: I fixed my post to include your fix, as well. :)

Comment: No, this causes me to no longer get 8.80 (lowest val is 8.88), and I'm still getting 98.88

Comment: @B.ClayShannon The method in my answer displays "8.78, 98.87" for me. Does it show the same for you? If so, I think your query logic is incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

Your condition is not correct. Consider following:

```
int deptStartWhole = 8;
int startFraction = 79;
int deptEndWhole = 98;
int endFraction = 87;
```

and your condition is:

```
d.dept >= deptStartWhole && d.subdept >= startFraction
&& d.dept <= deptEndWhole && d.subdept <= endFraction
```

it will not return row with `dept = 12` and `subdept = 32`, because `32 >= 79` (`d.subdept >= startFraction` check) is not true.

I think your condition should be

```
((d.dept == deptStartWhole && d.subdept >= startFraction) || d.dept > deptStartWhole)
&& ((d.dept == deptEndWhole && d.subdept <= endFraction) || d.subdept < deptEndWhole)
```

It checked `subdept` only when `dept` is exactly the same, and otherwise just check `dept` part, because that's the important one.

```
return inventoryItems
    .Where(d => ((d.dept == deptStartWhole && d.subdept >= startFraction) || d.dept > deptStartWhole)
                && ((d.dept == deptEndWhole && d.subdept <= endFraction) || d.subdept < deptEndWhole))
    .OrderBy(o => o.dept)
    .ThenBy(s => s.subdept);
```

Comment: Okay, I may have to change this to a SQL statement, then, because I don't know how to convert that to LINQ.

Comment: You don't have to convert anything, just copy that into your `Where` call. You can use `&&` and `||` in there (that's why you don't need all these `Where` calls - one is enough, just use `&&`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, Marcin; it's still returning the 98.88 record. I'm adding a scream shot to my original post, showing the data returned.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon OK, have you tried debugging that app and checking what values are calculated and how SQL query looks like?

Answer (score 2):

A suggestion: create a function that takes in the `deptNumber` and `deptSubNumber`, and returns a `decimal`. Then, use that function in-line in the `.Where()` statement to process the numbers as a single number, rather than using separate logic (treating dept and sub-dept separately) .

Comment: Better add this suggestion to your previous answer.

Comment: @Praveen Updated as per your suggestion. I'm assuming you're referring to updating the `.Where()` statement.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative suggestion: is it possible to create a calculated column on the database that simply combines the two fields together in the database, and returns it as a decimal?

Then, use that function in-line in the `.Where()` statement to process the numbers as a single number, rather than using separate logic (treating dept and sub-dept separately).

Following this, all of the department/sub-department logic in the C# code would be moot.